# Positive structure constants for rings with basis

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose $\mathbf{Z}^n$ is endowed with an associative ring structure so that the coefficient of $e_k$ in $e_i e_j$ is a nonnegative integer for every $i,j,k$.  Suppose the ring has an identity element $1$, so that $1 = a_1 e_1 + a_2 e_2 + \cdots + a_n e_n$.

Can any of the $a_i$ ever be negative?

If the $a_i$ are assumed nonnegative, then they are necessarily in $\{0,1\}$.  In fact in that case writing $1 = \sum_{s \in S} e_s$, for $S \subset \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, the $e_s$ must have $e_s^2 = e_s$ and $e_{s'} e_{s''} = 0$ for $s' \neq s''$.  I would like to know if this is always true (for a ring with basis with positive integer structure constants)

Comment: Can you show your ideas about the problem?

Comment: You are likely to receive answers if you show what work you have done on the problem and where you're stuck at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)$ with the basis $\{1+x,x\}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: +1. In accordance with the last paragraph of the question, this ring has no nontrivial idempotents. GLN: if you find this answer useful, you can upvote it (in addition to accepting, which you have already done)